# Why is this proof false? $\sqrt 2 + \sqrt 6 < \sqrt 15$

Tags: proof-verification

What is wrong with the given proof? 
$$
\sqrt 2 + \sqrt 6 < \sqrt 15 \\
(\sqrt 2 + \sqrt 6)^2 < 15 \\
2 + 6 + 2\sqrt2\sqrt6 < 15 \\
2\sqrt2\sqrt6 < 7\\
2^2 \cdot 2 \cdot 6 < 49 \\
48 < 49
$$

Comment: There is nothing wrong, as $\sqrt 2 + \sqrt 6 < \sqrt 15$ is true.

Comment: Well, for starters, there are no verbs connecting one line to the next.  Lacking such direction, the usual supposition is that one line *implies* the next.  In this case, you have *assumed* the thing that you are trying to show, then shown that it implies that $48 < 49$.  However, if you mean that line $n$ is true *if and only if* line $n+1$, then your proof is fine.

Comment: It's correct if you write it in reverse order.

Comment: No, reversing the lines does not make that correct. Words are missing — proofs are **explanations** of why something is true, and explanations use words, verbs, sentences, connectors and so on. A proof is a piece of text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As it stands, the proof is flawed, but not for any error of reasoning (really), but because it is argued in a slightly nonsensical manner.  Typically, when you write a sequence statements, you want to connect them to each other.  For example, "$A$ implies $B$" or "$A$ if and only if $B$".  If no such connecting verbs are stated, the usual assumption is that early statements *imply* later statements.  Thus, eliding all of the intermediate steps, one might reasonably read your proof as:

> If $\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{6} < \sqrt{15}$, then $48 < 49$.

This is, in fact, the converse of what you want to show.  There are two ways to make this more clear:

1. You could use language or notation to show that one line is true *if and only if* the previous line is true.  If you attacked it this way, you might write
   \begin{align}
   \sqrt{2} + \sqrt{6} < \sqrt{15}
     &\iff \left( \sqrt{2} + \sqrt{6} \right)^2 < \sqrt{15}^2 && \text{(since both sides are positive)} \\
     &\iff 2 + 2\sqrt{2}\sqrt{6} + 6 < 15 && \text{(distribution)} \\
     &\iff 2\sqrt{2}\sqrt{6} < 7 && \text{(law of additive cancelation)} \\
     &\iff 2^2\cdot 2 \cdot 6 < 7^2 && \text{(since both sides are positive)} \\
     &\iff 48 < 49. && \text{(simplify)}
   \end{align}
   Since $48<49$, the proposition is proved.
2. Alternatively, if you want to look clever, you write the proof as a series of implications:  we know that $48 < 49$.  Therefore
   \begin{align}
   48 < 49
     &\implies \sqrt{48} < \sqrt{49} \\
     &\implies 2 \sqrt{2}\sqrt{6} < 7 \\
     &\implies 2 + 2\sqrt{2}\sqrt{6} + 6 < 15 \\
     &\implies \left( \sqrt{2} + \sqrt{6} \right)^2 < 15 \\
     &\implies \sqrt{2} + \sqrt{6} < \sqrt{15},
   \end{align}
   where $\sqrt{x}$ denotes the principle (or positive) square root.

Another rather pathological approach might be to prove by contradiction.  Suppose that $\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{6} \ge \sqrt{15}$.  Using the basic computations that were originally given, but replacing $<$ with $\ge$, we obtain
$$ 48 \ge 49, $$
which is obvious nonsense.  Therefore it cannot be that $\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{6} \ge \sqrt{15}$, which proves the proposition.

Comment: Except steps $1$ and $4$ in method **1.** are not equivalences unless you explicltly state that you are using the positiveness of the two sides.

Comment: @dxiv Hence the caution that each step should really be checked carefully.  Though I'll admit that I was rather sloppy with that argument, as I think that it is kind of the Wrong Way(tm) to do things.  EDIT:  And fixed.

Comment: Could it be written as?

$$
\begin{align}
\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{6} < \sqrt{15}
  &\implies \left( \sqrt{2} + \sqrt{6} \right)^2 < \sqrt{15}^2 \\
  &\implies 2 + 2\sqrt{2}\sqrt{6} + 6 < 15  \\
  &\implies 2\sqrt{2}\sqrt{6} < 7 \\
  &\implies 2^2\cdot 2 \cdot 6 < 7^2 \\
  &\implies 48 < 49. && 
\end{align}
$$

Comment: @Viper No.  That is the way that one would have interpreted the original writeup, and that proves the converse of the desired statement, i.e. **if** $\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{6} < \sqrt{15}$, **then** $48 < 49$.  All you have done is shown that if the thing you want to prove is true, then you also know that $48 < 49$.  The fact that you know this for other reasons is utterly irrelevant.